# Python OrderedDict iteration

Tags: python, ordereddictionary

Why does my python OrderedDict get initialized 'out of order'?

The solution here is less intriguing than the explanation.   There's something here I just don't get, and perhaps an expanation would help others as well as me.

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict

>>> spam = OrderedDict(s = (1, 2), p = (3, 4), a = (5, 6), m = (7, 8))

>>> spam
OrderedDict([('a', (5, 6)), ('p', (3, 4)), ('s', (1, 2)), ('m', (7, 8))])

>>> for key in spam.keys():
...    print key    
...
#  this is 'ordered' but not the order I wanted....
a
p
s
m

# I was expecting (and wanting):
s
p
a
m
```

Comment: "kwargs" are not ordered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting dict to OrderedDict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711755/converting-dict-to-ordereddict)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects):

> The OrderedDict constructor and `update()` method both accept keyword arguments, but their order is lost because Python’s function call semantics pass-in keyword arguments using a regular unordered dictionary.

So initialization loses the ordering, because it's basically calling a constructor with `**kwargs`.

**Edit:** In terms of a *solution* (not just an *explanation*)—as pointed out [in a comment by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553506/python-ordereddict-iteration/16553551#comment23781738_16553551), passing in a single list of tuples *will* work:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> spam = OrderedDict([('s',(1,2)),('p',(3,4)),('a',(5,6)),('m',(7,8))])
>>> for key in spam:
...     print(key)
...
s
p
a
m
>>> for key in spam.keys():
...     print(key)
...
s
p
a
m
```

This is because it's only getting a single argument, a list.

Comment: so that's why this works:  

    OrderedDict([('s',(1,2)),('p',(3,4)),('a',(5,6)),('m',(7,8))]

in this case the constructor is getting a single argument, a [list]

thanks

Comment: This is solved with Python 3.6 right? from the docs - Changed in version 3.6: With the acceptance of PEP 468, order is retained for keyword arguments passed to the OrderedDict constructor and its update() method.

Comment: @chris-krycho, the out-of-place order is preserved later right?

Answer (score 17):

@Chris Krycho gave a good explanation of why things fail.

If you look at the repr() of an OrderedDict you get a hint at how to impart order from the beginning: You need to use a list of (key, value) pairs to preserve the order of the keys given by the list.

Here's one I did earlier:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> spamher = OrderedDict(s=6, p=5, a=4, m=3, h=2, e=1, r=0)
>>> spamher
OrderedDict([('h', 2), ('m', 3), ('r', 0), ('s', 6), ('p', 5), ('a', 4), ('e', 1)])
>>> 
>>> list(spamher.keys())
['h', 'm', 'r', 's', 'p', 'a', 'e']
>>> 
>>> spamher = OrderedDict([('s', 6), ('p', 5), ('a', 4), ('m', 3), ('h', 2), ('e', 1), ('r', 0)])
>>> list(spamher.keys())
['s', 'p', 'a', 'm', 'h', 'e', 'r']
>>>
```

(It just so happened that in Python v3.3.0 your original example of `spam` kept the keys in their original order from the outset. I changed to `spamher` to get arounf this).

Answer (score 4):

As the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16553551/1612701) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16554551/1612701) have mentioned, trying to pass a dict to OrderedDict or using keyword arguments doesn't preserve the order.  Passing in tuples is kinda ugly, though, and this is Python.  It should be beautiful.

You can <strike>ab</strike>use `__getitem__` on a class in order to have dict-like syntax for creating OrderedDict "literals":

```
from collections import OrderedDict
class OD(object):
    """This class provides a nice way to create OrderedDict "literals"."""
    def __getitem__(self, slices):
        if not isinstance(slices, tuple):
            slices = slices,
        return OrderedDict((slice.start, slice.stop) for slice in slices)
# Create a single instance; we don't ever need to refer to the class.
OD = OD()
```

Now you can use dict-like syntax to create an OrderedDict:

```
spam = OD['s': (1, 2), 
          'p': (3, 4), 
          'a': (5, 6), 
          'm': (7, 8)]
assert(''.join(spam.keys()) == 'spam')
```

This works because inside the square brackets, Python creates [slice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) literals, which happen to look like dict syntax if you squint a little.

The `OD` class could benefit from error checking, but this demonstrates how it can work.