# How to preserve the ordering of keys when declaring a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

My goal is to preserve the ordering of keys in a dictionary declaration. I am using `collections.OrderedDict` but when I run:

```
>>> modelConfigBase = OrderedDict({'FC':'*','EC':'*','MP':'*','LP':'*','ST':'*','SC':'*'})
```

The order changes:

```
>>> modelConfigBase
OrderedDict([('EC', '*'), ('ST', '*'), ('FC', '*'), ('MP', '*'), ('LP', '*'), ('SC', '*')])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Once the dictionary is created, there is no key ordereing. In your case, the dictionary which is created already is passed to `OrderedDict`

Comment: The repr value that prints in the interactive interpreter shows you how to create the object. In this case, use a list of tuples.

Comment: Duplicate of [Converting Dict() to OrderedDict()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711755/converting-dict-to-ordereddict)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dictionary that you are passing to `OrderedDict` is unordered.  You need to pass an ordered iterable of items . . .

e.g.

```
modelConfigBase = OrderedDict([
    ('FC', '*'),
    ('EC', '*'),
    ('MP', '*'),
    ('LP', '*'),
    ('ST', '*'),
    ('SC', '*')])
```

---

Note that, in this case (since all the values are the same), it looks like you could get away with the simpler:

```
modelConfigBase = OrderedDict.fromkeys(['FC', 'EC', 'MP', 'LP', 'ST', 'SC'], '*')
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on thefourtheye response the solution is as follows:

```
modelConfigBase = OrderedDict([('EC', '*'), ('ST', '*'), ('FC', '*'), ('MP', '*'), ('LP', '*'), ('SC', '*')])
```