# Keeping the columns order when making a DataFrame from Series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

When I try to make a `dataframe` of these two series with differing indices pandas doesn't preserve the order of the columns from the series as shown below.

```
index = ['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten']
index2 = index[:9] + ['Ha']

a = pd.Series(list(range(10)), index = index)
b = pd.Series(list(range(10)), index = index2)*2

df = pd.DataFrame([a,b], index = ['tens','times2'])
```

Outputs

```
Ha  eight   five    four    nine    one     seven   six     ten     three   two
```

But when I make the `dataframe` with the series having the same indices the original column order (the order of the list `index`) is preserved. Why is this happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a DataFrame while preserving order of the columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36539396/how-to-create-a-dataframe-while-preserving-order-of-the-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when the indices of 2 `Series` don't match Pandas will merge them together and place the columns in alphabetical order. This makes the columns of the DataFrame have the order I guess you expect you need to reorder them after you've made the DataFrame.

`df = pd.DataFrame([a, b], index=['tens', 'times2'])
df = df.reindex_axis(index + ['Ha'], axis='columns')`

`df.reindex_axis` is faster way of doing `df = df[index + ['Ha']]`