# How can i pass the requests body in the original order when the body dictionary is declared in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, python-requests

I got stuck when I try to send a post request with a large body dictionary.
Here is the code.

```
body = {"session":{"user":{"user_id":"user1"}, \
"equipment":{"equipment_id_alternate":{"alternate_equipment_id_type":"sms_address", \
"alternate_equipment_id":"equipmentid1"}, \
"extensions":[{"extension_type":"string","name":"device_type","value":"PC_Apple"}, \
{"extension_type":"string","name":"device_id", \
"value":"equipmentid1"}]}, \
"content":{"content_type":"http_broadcast_channel", \
"uri":"http://xyz/abc.m3u8", \
"extensions":[{"extension_type":"integer","name":"bandwidth","value":0}, \
{"extension_type":"string","name":"stream_quality","value":"HD"}, \
{"extension_type":"string","name":"session_type","value":"Live_Linear_Companion"}]}}, \
"sa_version":"sa_http_v_1_0_1","request_type":"setup_request", \
"authentication":{"auth_algorithm":"sa_hmac_token_v_1_0_1","auth_message_algorithm":"sa_http_auth_message_v_1_0_1", \
"auth_token_start":"2016-11-23T19:49:56Z","auth_token_expiry":"2016-11-30T19:49:56Z", \
"auth_token":"abdcwgegegegege"}}

header19 = {some keys and values}
api19 = requests.post(url19, json=body, headers=header19)
```

I want to pass the request body the same order as it is declared, how can i achieve it?

I see a lot of similar questions and replies saying that you can use collections.orderDict(); However I do not know how I can use it properly without declaring each key and value pair using collections.orderDict().

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest removing your `auth_token` value from the question body :)

Comment: @AminEtesamian, thanks, actually that is machine generated token and cannot used anywhere else. changed it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A regular dict does not track the insertion order, and iterating over it produces the values in an arbitrary order. In an OrderedDict, by contrast, the order the items are inserted is remembered and used when creating an iterator.

```
import collections


print 'Regular dictionary:'
d = {}
d['a'] = 'A'
d['b'] = 'B'
d['c'] = 'C'
d['d'] = 'D'
d['e'] = 'E'

for k, v in d.items():
   print k, v

print '\nOrderedDict:'
d = collections.OrderedDict()
d['a'] = 'A'
d['b'] = 'B'
d['c'] = 'C'
d['d'] = 'D'
d['e'] = 'E'


for k, v in d.items():

 print k, v
```

The output will be :

```
Regular dictionary:
a A
c C
b B
e E
d D
```

OrderedDict:

```
a A
b B
c C
d D
e E
```

Comment: actually i do not want to specify values for each key and sub-keys. that is going to be pain.

Comment: actually I was explaining the concept behind it. the mikeqfu's answer is better

Answer (score -1):

You may just try:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

ordered_body = OrderedDict(body)
```

The order of keys in `ordered_body` should remain the same as specified. I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711755/converting-dict-to-ordereddict) explains `OrderedDict` very clearly.

Comment: @AminEtesamian, did you try it? if i try to print ordered_body, i still got the result in a random order.

Comment: check the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711755/converting-dict-to-ordereddict