# Sort dictionary Based on its dictionary values in python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have nested dictionary like this :

```
dic = {
    1:
    {
        'name': 'alice',
        'point': 10
    },
    2:
    {
        'name': 'john',
        'point': 12
    }
    3:
    {
        'name': 'mike',
        'point': 8
    }
    4:
    {
        'name' : 'rose',
        'point': 16
    }
    5:
    {
        'name': 'ben',
        'point': 5
    }
}
```

In my case, i need to sort descending that dictionary based on the values of key 'point' in the second level.. So the result will be like this:

```
{
    4:
    {
        'name' : 'rose',
        'point': 16
    },
    2:
    {
        'name': 'john',
        'point': 12
    },
    1:
    {
        'name': 'alice',
        'point': 10
    },
    3:
    {
        'name': 'mike',
        'point': 8
    },
    5:
    {
        'name': 'ben',
        'point': 5
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do that? Thanks..

Comment: Dictionaries don't have an order

Comment: No. Dictionaries have no order. It doesn't make sense to say "sort a dictionary".

Comment: I would suggest that you review your data structure. Why do you need the first level number keys in you dict at all?

Comment: I mean, there are OrderedDictionaries - you just cant use a regular dictionary

Comment: You could also use a nested list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, in dictionary form you cannot sort these items.  However, here is a solution that may work depending on your needs, converting to key,value tuples and then sorting by points (which is implied by your output but not explicitly stated).

```
d = {
    4:
    {
        'name' : 'rose',
        'point': 16
    },
    2:
    {
        'name': 'john',
        'point': 12
    },
    1:
    {
        'name': 'alice',
        'point': 10
    },
    3:
    {
        'name': 'mike',
        'point': 8
    },
    5:
    {
        'name': 'ben',
        'point': 5
    }
}

d_sorted = sorted(d.items(), key = lambda x: x[1]['point'],reverse=True)
print(d_sorted)
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot sort "that dictionary". Dictionaries are orderless. However, you can use a nested list or other things people suggested in the comments. For ordered dictionaries, I suggest you look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711755/converting-dict-to-ordereddict).